# explode() and end() don't generate any output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get my account page's endpoint, language independent. `get_permalink` code generates proper link "https://example.com/my-account/", but I have problems extracting the last part, in eng version "my-account". Echo line which I put for troubleshooting, doesn't generate anything.

```
$my_acc = explode( '/', get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')));    
echo end($my_acc);
```

Comment: last element will be empty as your url has  a trailing slash, you can get the last non empty element with `$my_acc = array_filter($my_acc);
echo end($my_acc);`

Comment: Remove end slash from `https://example.com/my-account/` and try this URL ` https://example.com/my-account` You will definitely get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rtrim` first to remove last `/`

```
 $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id'));
 $url =   rtrim($url , '/');
 $my_acc = explode( '/', $url);
 echo end($my_acc);
```

Demo with `/`: https://eval.in/1094094
Demo without `/`: https://eval.in/1094096